# E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian focal Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, docker

```
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian focal Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I'm getting this error when I tried installing docker from [official docker site](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/). Anyhow, now I don't want it, but I can't find it anywhere in sources. I ran

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

but I cant find the docker repository to remove. How do I remove docker repository?

Comment: Also check the files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

Comment: The instructions clearly use `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`

Comment: Thank you both of you, it helped!

Comment: The correct line should be https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu . Or if you are  really using Debian, then it is off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

Run

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

comment the line, save, voila! Finished, your problem solved!